# Spritesheet offset from spritebuilder

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet, spritebuilder

I´m doing a puzzle game and has three pieces aligned horizontally. The pieces have empty pixels which are trimmed when making the spritesheet and gets the corresponding offset. When I make the spritesheet in spritebuilder the three pieces will have x-offset (from left to right): -177, 23, 0.

If i do the the same in texturepacker the same pieces will have offset: -177,22,200.

The texturepacker result makes much more sense since the offset for piece 3 is bigger than piece 2. (also the interval seem more accurate)

Am I missing something or is it a bug in spritebuilder? (I'm using  1.3.1-rc.1)

Comment: so, is there an issue with the app itself, or is this a question about .plists and their format ?

Comment: the issue is in the .plist

Comment: so it is not an issue then.

Comment: To clarify, the issue lies in the plist which leads to issues in the app. The scaling is done from tablet-hd (4x) in sprite builder and the offsets and sourceColorRect in the tablet-hd spritesheets turns out right. The issue lies in the spritesheets that are scaled down. So my guess is that it is an scaling issue in sprite builder.

Answer (score 0):

two texture packing programs will pack the textures differently. Compare the two atlas images and you'll see that they are (almost certainly) not identical.

even within the same app the actual layout may change between two export/publishing runs.

the whole point of texture atlases is that you needn't worry about any of the offsets, trimming and rotation properties of an image within the atlas - it's handled transparently by the engine.